# Joining Multiple Columns to the Same DIM Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table that has 8 columns of IDs that I will be joining to my DIM table. The table has 100K+ rows of IDs. Is there a more efficient way to join the IDs to my DIM table rather than using my code provided?

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | ... | ID8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 789 | 658 | ... | 987 |

```
SELECT F.ID1, D1.NAME, F.ID2, D2.NAME, F.ID3, D3.NAME, etc.
FROM FACT_TABLE AS F
LEFT JOIN DIM AS D1
  ON D1.ID = F.ID1
LEFT JOIN DIM AS D2
  ON D2.ID = F.ID2
LEFT JOIN DIM AS D3
  ON D3.ID = F.ID3
LEFT JOIN DIM AS D4
  ON D4.ID = F.ID4
...
LEFT JOIN DIM AS D8
  ON D8.ID = F.ID8
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, if you need the data from each of those rows you need to join them, there is no shortcut for joining multiple rows in one go... and why would you care?

Comment: Are your tables indexed by all this `ID` columns?

Comment: You could UNPIVOT your FACT_Table ... Perform the JOIN to DIM ... and then PIVOT for the final results.

Comment: @DaleK, perhaps he's busy writing all those LEFT JOINs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on my comment.   Not sure if this would be more performant.

**Example**

```
with cte as ( 
Select N.*
 From  Fact_Table A
 Cross Apply ( values ('id1',ID1)
                     ,('id2',ID2)
                     ,('id3',ID3)
                     ,('id4',ID4)
                     ,('id5',ID5)
                     ,('id6',ID6)
                     ,('id7',ID7)
                     ,('id8',ID8)
             ) B(Item,Value)
 Join Dim D on B.value=D.ID
 Cross Apply ( values (A.ID,B.Item,concat('',B.Value))
                     ,(A.ID,concat(B.Item,'_Name'),D.Name)
             ) N(ID,Item,Value)
)
Select *
 From  cte src
 Pivot ( max(value) for Item in ([id1],
                                 [id1_Name],
                                 [id2],
                                 [id2_Name],
                                 [id3],
                                 [id3_Name],
                                 [id4],
                                 [id4_Name], 
                                 [id5],
                                 [id5_Name], 
                                 [id6],
                                 [id6_Name], 
                                 [id7],
                                 [id7_Name], 
                                 [id8],
                                 [id8_Name]
                                ) ) pvt
```